# How to get data from Application class to PhoneStateListener class?

Tags: android-activity, event-listener, android

I have an Android app that has an Application class and I have another class that extends `PhoneStateListener`.

I would like to use one of the objects from the Application class in my class that extends the PhoneStateListener. I wasn't able to do so because it the `PhoneStateListener` class doesn't extend `Activity`.

Is there any way I can use the object from the `Application` class within my `PhoneStateListener` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/07/listening-to-phone-calls-using.html) example and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700109/1289716) Question

Answer (score 0):

Extend `PhoneStateListener` and have a constructor that takes what it wants as argument.