# How to get updates of network type with PhoneStateListener in Android 7 and higher?

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I have the following code that tells when the phone is connected to EDGE or UMTS network.  It works on Android 6 (API 23) but when I test
on Android 7 shows the network type only when I launch the app for first time, but there is no update when the phone changes from 2G to 3G and vice versa.

What is needed in order to make this code works updating the newtwork type in the moment that happens for Android 6 and 7+?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    PhoneStateListener ConnectionStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state, int networkType) {
            super.onDataConnectionStateChanged(state, networkType);
            String sState = "";

            switch (networkType) {
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:   sState = "EDGE (2G)";   break;
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:   sState = "UMTS (3G)";   break;                    
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sState, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    telephonyManager.listen(ConnectionStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
}
```

}

I've added to Manifest file the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission as shown below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Lucas pointed out this is most likely due to the `ConnectionStateListener` being garbage collected. You can fix it simply by moving your listener out of the function to make it a class field:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PhoneStateListener ConnectionStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state, int networkType) {
            super.onDataConnectionStateChanged(state, networkType);
            String sState = "";

            switch (networkType) {
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                    sState = "EDGE (2G)";
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                    sState = "UMTS (3G)";
                    break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sState, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(ConnectionStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
    }
}
```

This way you will keep the reference to the `PhoneStateListener`, preventing it from being garbage collected.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried like you said and it seems to show the update only on emulator. On real phones with android 6 and 7 only shows the network type when the app is launched. When I change between 2G and 3G any change appears with Toast()  on display. How to fix that?

Comment: Is your app in the foreground when your are switching network type? Toasts are not displayed when your app is not in the foreground.

Comment: The app is in foreground. Actually for what I've tested, Toast shows the updates even if the app is in background. When I test my original code in Android 6 it works in foreground and background. But with the code you kindly suggested, even in Android 6 is not showing any update in foreground nor background.

Comment: I've tried the code in the accepted answer in the link shared by Lucas that is to show state for calls and in that case in Android 7 it worked for me, when I tried to use the Phonelistener in the same way of that solution for network type it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in your listener and debug it? Isn't it called a t all?

Comment: how can I debug with a real phone? Because when I run the app in emulator for Android 6, 7 and 8 it works, but in a real phone with Android 7 doesn't show updates.

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in PhoneStateListener in Android 7

I think your question is related to this [Android Nougat PhoneStateListener is not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213250/android-nougat-phonestatelistener-is-not-triggered)

Comment: Thanks Lucas for your answer. I'll check the link you shared and see is that is a solution for this. Meanwhile maybe someone else shares another answer if there is another.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ConnectivityManagerCompat`. Or you can also use below code

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    String subtype = activeNetwork.getSubtypeName();
```

if you want to keep observing it then register a dynamic broadcast receiver with intent filter "ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION". Please note static receiver might not work post android 6.0

For implementation details 
mark this entry in manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receivers.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="@bool/connectivity_change_receiver_enabled"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And make sure that @bool/connectivity_change_receiver_enabled  is true for <=6.0 and false for >=7.0
and then for 7.0 use below code in your Applicaiton class

```
Context.registerReceiver(new ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver(),
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
```

After that you will get all the network related chagnes notified in  onReceive of ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver

inside values folder define a bools.xml file with following content

```
<resources>    
<bool name="connectivity_change_receiver_enabled">true</bool>
```

now create another folder named values-v24 parallel to values with following content

```
  <resources>    
<bool name="connectivity_change_receiver_enabled">false</bool>
```

Now you will be able to use the boolean in manifest and then put the dynamic registration of ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver inside API level check

Full code for ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "ConnectivityReceiver";

/**
 * Informs the service that we have network connectivity.
 *
 * @param context
 *        The application context
 * @param intent
 *        An Intent carrying information about the event
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "inside method onReceive::ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver");
    // if we are equal to or above API 23 then we can detect if device is in idle mode.
    // so we will do nothing if device is in idle mode
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if(powerManager.isDeviceIdleMode()) {
            // log("returning since device is in idle/doze mode");
            Log.d(TAG, "returning since device is in idle/doze mode");
            return;
        }
    }

    // Do nothing if this is received right after this broadcast is registered.
    if (isInitialStickyBroadcast()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"This is a initial sticky broadcast. Do nothing.");
        return;
    }


    // either use conventional method
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Intent notifyToActivity = new Intent("com.network.state.changed");
    String netType = "unknown";

    if(connectivityManager!= null) {
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(activeNetwork!= null) {
            netType = activeNetwork.getSubtypeName();
            Toast.makeText(context, "network state is " + netType, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    notifyToActivity.putExtra("NET_TYPE",netType);
    context.sendBroadcast(notifyToActivity);

}
```

}

Full Code for MainActivity:

```
ublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

TextView textureView;
NetworkStateListener networkStateListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    textureView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.network_type);

    networkStateListener = new NetworkStateListener();
    this.registerReceiver(networkStateListener, new IntentFilter("com.network.state.changed"));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(networkStateListener!= null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(networkStateListener);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


class  NetworkStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent!= null){
            String type = intent.getExtras().getString("NET_TYPE");
            textureView.setText(type);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Full Code for NetworkAppClass:

```
public class NetworkAppClass extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        this.registerReceiver(new ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver(),
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
}
```

}

Full code for Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:name=".NetworkAppClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="@bool/connectivity_change_receiver_enabled"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Screenshot to change network dynamically from emulator
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for answer. Where in my sample code should I insert the code you suggest?

Comment: You can create an Android  broadcast receiver class and in the onReceive() you can execute this code. But once you get the network status make sure you pass it to the activity or nay other component. As mentioned originally make sure you register it statically for 6.0 and below and dynamically for 7.0 and above.

Comment: What do you mean by register statically for Android 6 and dynamically for 7? May you show an example in how to include/join your suggested code with the code I have so far please?

Comment: you need to provide entry to broadcast receiver in manifest file for <=6.0 and for >=7.0 you need to use context.registerReceiver() method in application class

Comment: have added implementation details to original answer. Please have a look

Comment: Just created a sample and added each class code into original answer. you can verify this on emulator by using adb shell "svc data enable/disable" and cellular section in extended bar of emulator, you need to change the network type from emulator and then run the above command with first disabling and then enabling it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far. I've followed you and I created a new project with `MainActivity.java`,  `ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java`, `NetworkAppClass.java`, `../values/bools.xml`, `../res/menu/menu_main.xml` and `/../res/values-v24/values.xml`. I pasted the code in corresponding files and did `Alt+Enter` to fix the "Red words". I commented the toolbar lines because was the unique error I couldn't fix. Then I run it and nothing updates when I change network type. Is possible for you to share the project in zip format so I can try? maybe something is missing for me

Comment: I'm not sure if you received my previous comment. If possible for you guide what could be missing for me, since I don't get updates when network type changes. If possible maybe you can share the project that worked for you and I could import it and try it. Thanks again